# Exposing a Web Api Rest Service, without controller name to access its methods

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have a rest service developed with ASP.NET Web Api.
The controller in this example is MyTestController.
In the route template, I set `"api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"` . It has a simple GET method "hello", that returns a string.
So if I try to call this service while it is running, I should do a GET http://localhost/api/MyTest/hello .
What I would like to obtain instead is to be able to call it as GET http://localhost/hello , so removing the api/controller part.

Is that possible?

I have already tried to set `routeTemplate: "/{action}/{id}"` but it obviously does not work.

This is an example of service

```
  public class MyTestController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public string Hello()
        {
            return "service is online";
        }
}
```

And this is the code extract with the routing settings:

```
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Comment: define *but it obviously does not work* ... did you pass controller to defaults ... it's written in first google result for "MapHttpRoute" (which means that it takes less time to ask google then writing the question here)

Comment: Sorry Selvin, I meant that by just setting routeTemplate: "{action}/{id}" it apparently doesn't work. I have just a bit of knowledge in Asp.Net Web Api routing, and having small time to try it, I did some simple test. I usually expose one or more controllers accessible with their unique names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this, bellow

```
// Register the static hello route
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
     name: "HelloRoute",
     routeTemplate: "api/hello",
     defaults: new { controller = "MyTest", action = "Hello" }
);
// If it does not match, then fallback to the generic matcher
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
     name: "DefaultApi",
     routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
     defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Take a look at the [microsoft routing guide for web api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api) to see how the matching happens and what default options you have.

Bear in mind that you choose wisely the reason why you want something like this. In case of rest apis we want to have routes like    hostname/resource/id/sub-resource/id

You can read about rest api (which are resource based) [here](https://github.com/microsoft/api-guidelines/blob/vNext/Guidelines.md)

Comment: Hello Athanasios, thank you for your answer, I looked at the code and read some of the microsoft routing guide. Your solution is just what I was looking for, thank you! I just modified the defaults part to this : `defaults: new { controller = "MyTest", action = "Hello"}` because it gave me this error message "An error has occurred.Multiple actions were found that match the request". Thank you!

Comment: You are quite right. I modified the answer to work account for the action.